# Does internal HDD read/write speed affect external HDD read/write speed?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have a Samsung Series 7 laptop with a Hitachi HTS727575A9E364 internal HDD, and was wondering if purchasing a Buffalo DriveStation DDR 2TB HDD would be worth it. Would the speed of my internal HDD limit the speed this external HDD could achieve? I would be attaching it to the laptop via USB 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

The speed of the internal drive would only limit the speed of the external drive if you were copying from one drive to the other. Otherwise, they have no effect on each other.

Answer (score 0):

The external drive will run at the speed determined by its connection (USB 3.0, in your case).  The internal drive won't affect its transfer speed at all.  Rather than the drive you're considering, I'd probably get something like the [Seagate FreeAgent GoFlex Home 2 TB](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003STVG80).  That's a connectivity and personal taste thing, though so you may not agree.

Answer (score 0):

If copying from external to internal you are limited to the internals hard drive write speed.  However, most hard drives are about the same.  You can attach the hard drive to a USB 3.0 port but it will not reach anywhere near the max USB 3.0 can do.

[Read this review](http://www.storagereview.com/buffalo_drivestation_ddr_review_hdgdu3)

For files >1gb in size file speeds revert back to normal hard drive speeds.  The other danger listed is if power loss occurs during a write you will corrupt those files and have to rewrite them or get a UPS to backup the power.